# How to install PHPExcel in symfony2.5 using netbeans

Tags: symfony, netbeans, symfony1, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I am facing problem with PHPExcel installation in symfony2.5.

I have downloaded PHPExcel directory from GitHub and I dont know the configuration steps. 
as I am beginner I would need complete steps to understand the complete installation process,

Please help me regarding this,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean how do you use it or how do you make the classes available?

Comment: I want to access the class from my controller, I have copied the PHPExcel directory to Vendor folder

Comment: You shouldn't copy anything to your vendor directory. See my answer.

Comment: How to make the classes available or how to call these classes from my controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it to your `composer.json` or require it with composer (`php composer.phar require "phpoffice/phpexcel:1.8.0`) like most other php packages which will then add it to the class loader meaning you can just use it like `\PHPExcel_...`.

The available packages for it are [on packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel).

If you are wanting to use the classes from a version that you have downloaded you can add them to your `src` directory and they will be autoloaded there through the default autoload setting.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/"}
},
```

Comment: I am trying to read excel sheet and insert into the Mysql database. Do you have any suggestion...?--- thanks in advance

Comment: Try searching google. I did and on the first page was - http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695695/how-to-use-phpexcel-to-read-data-and-insert-into-database, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156228/reading-a-xlsx-sheet-to-feed-a-mysql-table-using-phpexcel & http://runnable.com/Uot2A2l8VxsUAAAR/read-a-simple-2007-xlsx-excel-file-for-php.